# Is there a way to compute the orientability of a surface embedded in 3D and represented by a collection of datapoints?

Tags: geometry, algorithms, low-dimensional-topology, non-orientable-surfaces

First of all, I am sorry if some concepts in this description are not accurate. I have no knowledge of topology, but my research has brought me to a situation in which topology is necessary.

I have a series of datapoints in 3D that lie along a 2D surface (for example a Mobius strip, but it is actually a bit more complicated than that and cannot be easily interpreted by simple visualization). Let us assume that the density of points is high enough (relative to the maximum curvature) to describe the surface unambiguously, so that you cannot have a sudden twist in the space between two data points.

Are there any methods to compute whether this surface is orientable or not?

Thanks in advance for any insights into this.

Comment: I think there is a problem because it seems we can always find two surfaces, one orientable and one non-orientable, such that both of these surfaces are "good interpolations" of the points

Comment: Is it so? Take the example of a mobius strip. Is there no way to tell it is a non-orientable surface by looking at relationships between points that lie along the surface?

Comment: Hmmm... It seems to me that you could always untwist the Möbius loop into a normal loop if you only are controlled by finitely many points...

Comment: You could pick out a representative sample of points and connect them into a triangularization of the surface. Then attempt to assign orientations to the triangles. If you can do it consistently for all of them, then it is orientable.

Comment: But say that the density of the points is enough, relative to the maximum curvature in the surface (not really sure of what 'enough' means here, but let's say it is very high). Are there not any algorithms developed to work even if under certain constraints?

Comment: So, picking up on the reply by Somos, I should assign the same orientation to neighboring triangles (sharing one side and standing almost in the same plane). If it is non-oriented eventually I should find neighbouring triangles with opposite directions. Any idea of a toolbox that does this, before I try to do it myself?